# Alternatives to table view within a table view for two levels of detail view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, user-interface

Imagine an app that allowed the Beatles to work on multiple albums at the same time. So on the left you have a list of two albums (Abbey Road and Sergent Pepper's) and if you select Abbey Road, it gives you a list of all the songs on Abbey Road. If you select one of those songs ("Come Together" in the example below), it opens the text of that song in a detail view and allows you to edit the song lyrics. So instead of a Master Detail set up, it's like a Master Master Detail arrangement with two table views and a detail view. Persistence will be done with Core Data.

Is this the recommended way to do it? I've seen some comments online that nesting table views is not great UI.

```
TableView                 TableView                                 Detail

    Albums (list)              **AbbeyRoad**   (songlist)            Come Together (songtext)

    1.AbbeyRoad            ComeTogether                       Here come old flattop blah blah
    2.Sergent Pepper's     Something 
                           Maxwell's Silver Hammer
```

Comment: I guess you need this https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never, ever, ever put one table view inside another. Gack. That's a user interface disaster in the making.

You could use a sectioned table view, where the sections are albums, and the rows within a section are the songs.

For iPad, you could have side-by-side table views, but that doesn't work on iPhone.

Apple intends you to use a split view controller for that on iPad, and a sequence of master>detail>sub_detail view controllers on iPhone. You can go down as many levels as needed.

Comment: Isn't a `master > detail >sub_detail` set up similar?  if I used that pattern, the `detail` would contain a list of songs, each of which would need to be able to segue to a sub_detail with the lyrics for each song. Can you explain how your suggestion is much different?

Comment: Different from what? I got the impression you were talking about trying to put table views inside each cell of a table view, which would be a disaster.